# form post of values in array and manage them divided by key

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I dont know how to manage this situation, I'm a noob coder, I have a page that shows you all available lots where you can unload a specific item from that lot.

This is the foreach that prints out:

`$lotto`, `$totalelotto`, `$data`, and ask for qtyvalue to unload from `$lotto` (input can be also NULL)

```
foreach ($dataslotto as $data) {
    $totalelotto = totlotto($database, $data['lotto']);
    $lotto = $data["lotto"];
    $data = $data["data"];
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$lotto."</td>";
    echo "<input type=\"hidden\" value=\"".$lotto."\" name=\"array[]\" />";
    echo "<td>".$totalelotto."</td>";
    echo "<input type=\"hidden\" value=\"".$totalelotto."\" name=\"array[]\" />";
    echo "<td>".$data."</td>";
    echo "<input type=\"hidden\" value=\"".$data."\" name=\"array[]\" />";
    echo "<td><input type=\"text\" class=\"form-control\" placeholder=\"Qta.\" required name=\"qtyvalue\"></td>";
    echo "</tr>";

}
```

I dont know how to set `name=""` of input fields (because the number of fields can change if there are many lots) and I dont know how to send `$_POST` data as array, and then foreach group of `$lotto`, `$totalelotto`, `$data`, `$qtyvalue` where is set `$qtyvalue` do another query.

I put it in no regular code, I know it looks bad but it's just for giving you an idea.

```
$_POST[''formarray];
foreach ( /* values recieved in each <tr> inside formarray where $_POST['qtyvalue'] is not empty */ ){
    #EXECUTE THIS
}
```

[image: FORM]

Thanks for help!!

And sorry for my bad coding skills.

Comment: The names of your inputs should probably like `lotto[]`, `totalelotto[]` and `data[]`, instead of `array[]` for all of them (this would also work, but you have to process the elements in batches of 3 then). I assume you are aware of the [PHP feature that automatically creates arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays) if you name your inputs this way, or is this what you are asking about?

Comment: I didnt know that in this way it autopopulates the array so after post if I have $_POST['lotto'],$_POST['totalelotto']... right?

Comment: Yes, each one of those $_POST variables would be an array, elements with the same index would belong together (represent one row of your table).

Comment: And how can assign key 0 of array $_POST['lotto'] to a variable $lotto ? For example Array ( [0] => abc123 [1] => qwe321 [2] => ee3dd ) assign $lotto0 abc123 , $lotto1 qwe321

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST` is an Associative/Key Value pair, it's key is whatever is set as the inputs name.

so if you wanted to send the users input `username` to the backend PHP script

You set the value and it's name

```
<input type="text" name="username" value="User123">
```

then to retrieve the user name you can do

```
print_r($_POST["username"]);
```

to print the value.

So you ask how do you loop over each one in $_POST, that's pretty simple you can could a foreach loop over the entire $_POST array.

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
{
    //check something has been entered for the current value we are iterating over
    if($value != null)
     {
        print_r($key . " value is : " . $value);
     }
}
```

this would loop over each item in the $_POST array with key being set to whatever the DOM elements name is.

Don't forget the $_POST array is just that an array, you could do

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

and see everything that was sent in the POST request.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array names for your inputs](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays). Say you have a row of your table like this:

```
<tr>
  <td><input ... name="lotto[]"></td>
  <td><input ... name="totalelotto[]"></td>
  <td><input ... name="data[]"></td>
  <td><input ... name="qtyvalue[]"></td>
</tr>
```

Then you will get arrays `$_POST['lotto']`, `$_POST['totalelotto']` and so on, each with the same number of elements, and elements with same index belonging to one row of the table. You could then process those elements like this

```
foreach ($_POST['lotto'] as $i=>$lotto) {
  if ($_POST['qtyvalue'][$i] > 0) {
     ...
  }
}
```